# Edit a 'hash url' in angular ui route

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to edit the placement of the hashtag in hashmode from `/#/` to `/#`?

When `html5mode` is not supported (in older browsers `IE9` and down)  and I get `hash URL` `/` `hashbang` mode

**what i get :**

```
'index.com/#/path/id'
```

**What I would like to get :**

```
'index.com/path/#id'
```

Is it possible to edit the URL / placement of the `hash-tag` from within the angular app config ? Or is what I want an unaccepted/invalid URL for hash mode?

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your router page

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: " When html5mode is not supported (in older browsers IE9 and down) and i get 'hash URL' / hashbang mode "

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove `#` from URL in a browser that does not support `history` API.

[From AngularJS Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#html5Mode), when `mode=true` in `html5Mode` :

> enabled – `{boolean}` – (`default: false`) If true, will rely on
>   `history.pushState` to change urls where supported. Will fall back to
>   `hash-prefixed` paths in browsers that do not support `pushState`.

[From `$locationProvider` source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L697), if `history.pushState`fails, it restores the old URL values:

```
function setBrowserUrlWithFallback(url, replace, state) {
      var oldUrl = $location.url();
      var oldState = $location.$$state;
      try {
        $browser.url(url, replace, state);

        // Make sure $location.state() returns referentially identical (not just deeply equal)
        // state object; this makes possible quick checking if the state changed in the digest
        // loop. Checking deep equality would be too expensive.
        $location.$$state = $browser.state();
      } catch (e) {
        // Restore old values if pushState fails
        $location.url(oldUrl);
        $location.$$state = oldState;

        throw e;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to remove it, i want to edit its placement in the URL like in the example i posted. 'index.com/path/#id'

Comment: `#` will be appended after the base URL. Your base URL is `index.com`. I don't think it's possible to achieve `index.com/path/#id`.